# mysql 8.0 instance on Windows : my.ini file is read but variables in there are ignored

Tags: mysql-8.0

I am trying to set various mysql settings in a mysql 8.0.30 instance on Windows 11 but my values are ignored.

Startup parameters for the mysql80 service are:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" MySQL80
```

If I look at that my.ini file I have:

```
[mysqld]
disable_log_bin
sort_buffer_size = 4194304
max_connections = 500
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 3221225472
```

If I add a nonsense setting here, mysql refuses to start up, so I know the file is being read

If I run 'mysqladmin variables' it is clearly ignoring my variables:

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0>mysqladmin variables -u root --password=password | grep -e innodb_buffer_pool_size -e max_connections
mysqladmin: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
| innodb_buffer_pool_size                                  | 134217728
|
| max_connections                                          | 151
|
| mysqlx_max_connections                                   | 100
```

Does anyone have any idea where the my.ini settings are getting overridden?

On Linux, mysql 8, placing those variables in the [mysqld] section (of /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf)  *does* work.

Answer (score 0):

OK so the answer is, when you install on Windows the config file (my.ini) already contains these settings and there's no warning that you have added a dupe. It just silently takes the value nearest the end of the file.

When you install on Linux the config file (my.cnf) already contains these settings too, but they are commented out.